# why my ec2 in one region is trying to use private IP of another ec2 instance in another region?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Our company has a github setup in an aws EC2 instance. This of course will have private/public ip.

I have setup two ec2 instances in a different region.

However, when I try connection to our company's github from one instance, it will use the public ip of the github instance. In this case, the connection is successful and I can clone and do stuff.

But the other will use private ip of the github instance. In this case, it fails to connect to the github instance.

BTW, the second one(the one that fails) was migrated from the region where github instance is setup, to a different region. Saved the AMI and relaunched it in the new region.

Here is an example describing my symptom.

I will assume:

- instanceA: migrated ec2 instance to new region
- instanceB: newly created ec2 instance in new region
- github instance: has domain name "git.blahblah.com". It has private IP of `172.31.xx.xx` , public IP of `52.78.xx.xx`

**instanceA**

```
$ ping git.blahblah.com
PING git.blahblah.com (172.31.xx.xx) 56(84) bytes of data.
```

**instanceB**

```
$ ping git.blahblah.com
PING git.blahblah.com (52.78.xx.xx) 56(84) bytes of data.
```

What can be causing it? Any hints on tackling this issue?

---

I have checked DNS settings by `$ cat /etc/resolv.conf

**instanceA**

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 172.30.0.2
search us-west-2.compute.internal
```

**instanceB**

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 172.30.0.2
search us-west-2.compute.internal
```

the security group of instanceA and instanceB is identical.
VPC ID, subnet ID of instanceA and instanceB is identical.

Comment: How is the "second one" referencing the GitHub server? Is it using an IP address or a DNS name? From the "second one", try resolving the DNS name of the GitHub server to see what is returned. Double-check that the configuration between the two servers match.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I've added updates regarding the DNS settings. It seems identical to me. any other approach ideas?

Answer (score 1):

How dumb of me.

The cause of this was that in instanceA(migrated from a different region) had some configurations in `/etc/hosts` file that forced `git.blahblah.com` to refer to the private IP of it.

```
$ cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1 localhost
172.31.xx.xx git.blahblah.com

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1 ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
ff02::3 ip6-allhosts
```

After I deleted `172.31.xx.xx git.blahblah.com` line from the `hosts` file, it worked.

Sorry for my stupidity people.

Comment: Glad you figured it out!

Answer (score 0):

Because your instances are in different regions from the github instance then they are not over the same network, and hence they can't connect to the private ip address.

If you want them to connect together over the same ip address then they need to be in the same VPC and to get there they need to be on the same region (but not the same availability zone)

> A private IPv4 address is an IP address that's not reachable over the
>   Internet. You can use private IPv4 addresses for communication between
>   instances in the same network (EC2-Classic or a VPC).

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-instance-addressing.html#concepts-private-addresses

Comment: but experiment with the second server on my new region shows that it can reach to the github instance with github instances' public IP.
But for some reason my migrated server keeps on using the private IP of the github instance, which as you said it, unreachable. 
How can I force it to use the public IP instead of private IP?

Comment: @kwagjj the question is a bit different than what I understood, what makes you think it's using the private ip? And how are you connecting to the github instance?

Comment: well, for one, I've tried pinging from these two different instances

instanceA:
$ ping git.blahblah.com
PING git.blahblah.com (172.31.xx.xx) 56(84) bytes of data.

instanceB:

$ ping git.blahblah.com
PING git.blahblah.com (52.78.xx.xx) 56(84) bytes of data.

Comment: Sounds like the dns might be cahced on the instance, can you try stopping it and starting it again (a full stop, not a restart)

Comment: unfortunately full stop -> start didn't solve the problem :(

Comment: This might be an overkill but I suspect that it's because the instance was migrated from the same region that this is affecting the way it resolves that domain name. So try doing this: - create a new ec2 instance in the same region as the failed instance and ping the server & see if you get the public or private ip & do the same thing on the region where your git ec2 is

Comment: If they are both resolving to the public ip then there's something wrong with the instance itself, and you can try creating an image from the instance that works, copying it to that other region and starting a new instance there.

Comment: Just solved it. It was my lack of knowledge and stupidity. The problem was lying in `/etc/hosts`. Sorry for taking up your time and effort. Really appreciate it. It helped me to dig in deeper.